# Getting error "Server Error in '/' Application." when I run the program

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have received an error message when I run my program. I feel this is a common type of error. Can you explain this error in simple terms.

```
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.searchbygenre_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'ddlGenre_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method 'ddlGenre_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.searchbygenre_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 6:      <p>
Line 7:          Choose a Genre:
Line 8:          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGenre" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGenre_SelectedIndexChanged">
Line 9:          </asp:DropDownList>
Line 10:     </p>

Source File: c:\Users\Jithma Senarathne\Desktop\fiverr\asp.net\Project\Cinema Website\Cinema Website\Cinema Website\SearchByGenre.aspx    Line: 8
```

Comment: How do I correct it ?

Comment: Add the missing method? `ddlGenre_SelectedIndexChanged`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message, in your front page (`c:\Users\Jithma Senarathne\Desktop\fiverr\asp.net\Project\Cinema Website\Cinema Website\Cinema Website\SearchByGenre.aspx`), you may have a dropdownlist (named `ddlGenre`) which is bound the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event `ddlGenre_SelectedIndexChanged`, but there doesn't have the method in the code behind in the `SearchByGenre.aspx.cs` file. What you should do is:

1. either remove the event binding code in front page `SearchByGenre.aspx` line 8:  `AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGenre_SelectedIndexChanged"`,
2. or add the event method at code behind in the `SearchByGenre.aspx.cs` file.